# How to escape parenthesis in grep

Tags: grep, escaping

I want to grep for a function call 'init()' in all JavaScript files in a directory. How do I do this using grep?

Particularly, how do I escape parenthesis, `()`?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It depends.  If you use regular grep, you don't escape:

```
echo '(foo)' | grep '(fo*)'
```

You actually have to escape if you want to use the parentheses as grouping.

If you use [extended regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions), you do escape:

```
echo '(foo)' | grep -E '\(fo*\)'
```

Comment: When I use grep -rin init()  * in the directory it complains syntax error near unexpected token (. How do I fix this.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand. I have a few javascript files, with a init() function called in few places in them. I want to find out where all init() is called, using grep -rin init() * in the directory..It complains about invalid syntax near (. How do I escape ( .

Comment: @Megha, just to clarify, that was a shell error because you didn't quote the regex.

Comment: My issue was that I did 
`grep "{"` instead of `grep '{'`.  Double quotes and single quotes makes a big difference for special characters for grep.

Comment: @Marcus Grep doesn't care (or know) whether you used double or single quotes. It's your shell that [parses the quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).

Answer (score 30):

If you want to search for exactly the string "init()" then use `fgrep "init()"` or `grep -F "init()"`.

Both of these will do fixed string matching, i.e. will treat the pattern as a plain string to search for and not as a regex.  I believe it is also faster than doing a regex search.

Comment: This does not work. It says "conflicting matchers specificed".

Answer (score 4):

```
$ echo "init()" | grep -Erin 'init\([^)]*\)'
1:init()

$ echo "init(test)" | grep -Erin 'init\([^)]*\)'
1:init(test)

$ echo "initwhat" | grep -Erin 'init\([^)]*\)'
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  It will just as easily match "initwhatever", since by default backslashed parens create capturing groups.  As I said above, you do not escape parens with regular grep.

Comment: I believe this is fine because the '-E' is equivalent to egrep.

Answer (score 2):

Move to your root directory (if you are aware where the JavaScript files are). Then do the following.

```
grep 'init()' *.js
```

Comment: in order to grep into all sub-folders recursively, suggest add parameter -r