# Regexp for matching filenames

Tags: regex, bash

I have a files:

```
first.error.log
second1.log
second2.log
FFFpc.log
TR.den.log
bla.error.log
```

and I would like to make a pattern that will match all files with error inside of filenames + few additional ones but no more:

For a sole error it would be

```
 $FILE_PATTERN="*.error*"
```

But what if I want to match not only those errors but also all second and FFpc etc?

This does not work:

```
$FILE_PATTERN="*.error*|^second.*\log$|.*FFPC\.log$"
```

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT:

$FILE_PATTERN is later used by:

```
find /somefolder -type f -name $FILE_PATTERN
```

EDIT: THIS FILE_PATTERN is in property file that is later used by bash script.

Comment: What command is using `$FILE_PATTERN`?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to match. You're using a mishmash of regex and wildcards without explanation, it's a terrible idea for conveying intent. If you used proper regex it would work (`.` means one character, `.*` means a string, `\.` means a dot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `find` with `-regex` option:

```
find -E /somefolder -type f -regex '\./(.*\.error.*|second.*log|.*FFPC\.log)$'
```

**PS:** Use `-iregex` for ignore case matching:

```
find -E /somefolder -type f -iregex '\./(.*\.error.*|second.*log|.*FFPC\.log)$'
```

Comment: `-E` is for extended regular expression.

Comment: I see. GNU `find` doesn't have it I think. With GNU, you do it with `-regextype <type>` where type can be `findutils-default`, `awk`, `egrep`, `ed`, `emacs`, `gnu-awk`, `grep`, `posix-awk`, `posix-basic`, `posix-egrep`, `posix-extended`, `posix-minimal-basic`, `sed`.

Comment: @konsolebox: Many thanks for adding note about `gnu find`. I was on OSX so couldn't test it using `gnu` version of `find`.

Comment: Actually, the main problem was that -name in a find command instead of -regex, after I changed it everything else went smoothly, thanks!

Comment: Yes that is true @MateuszChrzaszcz. What you has was indeed a regex pattern not a glob pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ls | grep -i '\(.*error.*\)\|\(^second.*\log$\)\|\(.*FFPC\.log$\)'
bla.error.log
FFFpc.log
first.error.log
second1.log
second2.log
```

If you wanted to use with find

```
find /somefolder -type f | grep -i '\(.*error.*\)\|\(^second.*\log$\)\|\(.*FFPC\.log$\)'
```

Comment: Why the escaped parenthesis?

Comment: @Blindy Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673594/how-to-escape-braces-in-grep

Comment: Oh interesting, I only use it from inside C# :)

Comment: @Hemang I think if you used `egrep` you wouldn't have to escape all the parens and pipes

Answer (score 1):

If you're in `bash` I'm assuming you have to `grep`. Using `grep -E` or `egrep` will allow you to use alternation (ORing your searches)

```
$ stat * | egrep "(error|second)"
File: `first.error.log'
File: `second1.log'
File: `second2.log'
```

You could use `ls` instead of `stat` but sometimes `ls` will not give you what you predicted. But considering you're only search for filenames, `ls` should suffice.

```
$ ls | egrep "(error|second)"
first.error.log
second1.log
second2.log
```

You can use command substitution to store the output into a `bash` variable:

```
FILE_PATTERN=$(ls | egrep "(error|second)")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FILE_PATTERN=("*.error*" "second.*log" ".*FFPC.log")
ARGS=(-name "$FILE_PATTERN")
for F in "${FILE_PATTERN[@]:2}"; do
    ARGS+=(-o -name "$F")
done
find /somefolder -type f '(' "${ARGS[@]}" ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close, theres just a few misplaced symbols.

Here's what I came up with:

```
.*\.error\..*|^second.*\.log$|.*FF[Pp][Cc]\.log$
```

here's a demo of a working modification of your regex:
http://regex101.com/r/rL3rM1/1